# call ajax response to be use in custom dialog callback function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**AJAX w/ bootbox custom dialog**

```
var checkRequApprove =  function ()
    { 
      $.ajax({
      url: '127.0.0.1/ProgVsProg/main/checkApproveReq',
      success:function(output){
        if(output==false){
         console.log(output);
         stopTime = setTimeout(checkRequApprove, 1000); 
            }
        else {
              bootbox.dialog({
              message: (output),
              title: "Request Accepted",
              buttons:
               {
                  success: {
                  label: "Approve",
                  className: "btn-success",
                  callback: function() {
                  var username = (output);
                       $.ajax({    
                          "type" : "POST",
                          "url" : "finalApprove",
                          "data" : {'username' : username},
                          success: function(data){
                            $('#example').html(data);
                          }
                     });
                  }
                  }, 
              }
              }); 
         stopCounter();
            }
    }
  });
}
    stopTime = setTimeout(checkRequApprove,1000);
```

**Controller**

```
public function checkApproveReq(){
$id = $this->session->userdata('userID');
$requApprove = '1';
$check = $this->lawmodel->checkRequApprove($id,$requApprove);
foreach($check as $row){
   if($row->requApprove == '1')
    {
       reqID = $this->lawmodel->getID($row->requestedID);
       foreach($reqID as $row){
       echo $row->username;
      }
    }
    else
        echo false;
    }
}
public function finalApprove(){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $userID = $this->session->userdata('userID');
    $id = $this->lawmodel->getUsernameID($username);
    $data= array(
            "challApprove" => "1",
        );
    $this->lawmodel->finalUpdateRequest($userID,$id,$data);

    echo "Accepting Please Wait!";
}
```

Im having this problem i dont know if im doing the correct way..
I want that the ajax response on `checkRequApprove` will be call back in the custom dialog success buttons `callback: function()`. I have put in the success button the response on checkRequApprove which is `output` inside the `var username` to be able to call back in the `callback: function`.

Base on my code below it seems that the `data:{'username' : username},` is not getting the value in `var username` that make the success function return no output.

pls help..im new in ajax..:(

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST:** the "output" var received by your success function is the whole jqXHR-Object.
What you are searching is the responseText - in your case `output.responseText`

**SECOND:** On your Server File, you are echoing true.
Since this is a HTML-response it comes as a String. So you have to check 
`if( output === 'FALSE')`

---

**BTW:** There are some more errors in your example. But i won't go to deep in here.
I recommend to get an better understanding of the [jqXHR-Object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) and Tools to inspect the browsers xhr-requests. like firebug or the native chrome devleoper toolbar

Comment: sry, i don't know the bootbox.dialog API and as io said i won't go to deep here. but i can say that you use "data" instead of "output" in your innerst success object and set username to output instead of the real response. but anyway it seems a little bit messy with this timeouts nested ajax calls and suspect snippets of your code.
i dont even know if checkApproveReq and/or finalApprove are ever executed.

I'm out - good luck

Comment: thanks anyway..i understand your idea..but using json_encode will also work..:)